# How to keep aspect ratio of Image and Watermark in Laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, watermark, aspect-ratio, intervention

I am trying to add Watermark of 800x100px to Images which can have any resolution greater than 800x100, i.e. 801x110, 1200x1000, 1300x200, 1920x1080, 4000x2010, etc.

I want to keep the aspect ratio of Watermark and image to **2:50**.
i.e., if image has 1000px width, then watarmark over image should occupy 20px(1000/50).

Here is my Function :

in **helper.php**

```
use Image;
//calling from Controller

public static function addwatermark ($name) {

  $thumbnail = Image::make($name);
  $imageWidth = $thumbnail->width();
  $watermarkWidth = '800px';

  $watermarkSource = 'public/img/watermark/watermark.png';
  $thumbnail->insert($watermarkSource, 'bottom-left', 0, 0);
  $thumbnail->save($name)->destroy();
}
```

in **ImageController.php**

```
 $folder = 'public/folder/';
 $large = 'myfile.jpeg';
 Helper::addwatermark($folder.$large);
```

Comment: You can use if case with Image Width and apply accordingly with few resized Watermark images.

Comment: @Amit Ratio will not be same still. some image can have the look with bigger watermark still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```php
public static function addwatermark ($name) {
{
    $thumbnail = Image::make($name);
    $imageWidth = $thumbnail->width();
    $watermarkSource =  Image::make(public_path('img/watermark/watermark.png'));

    $watermarkSize = round(20 * $imageWidth / 50);
    $watermarkSource->resize($watermarkSize, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });

    $thumbnail->insert($watermarkSource, 'bottom-left', 0, 0);
    $thumbnail->save($name)->destroy();
}
```

Comment: @AnonymousGirl are you using the `$watermarkSource` I provided or you are using the previous yours?

Comment: Sorry! it worked. But I will test it on different images and let you know!!!!

Comment: Original Image which is to be watermarked becomes 264KB from 2.05MB

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @AnonymousGirl Use `imagick` instead of `gd` in your intervention configs. You can find how to do it here http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean :
aspect ratio of watermark is ***8:1*** ( width of watermark is 8 times larger of its height )
and based on aspect ratio ***2:50*** or ***1:25***, width of the image is 25 times larger than width of watermark.
for example: if image has 1000px width, the watermark width, should be 40px.
so we also pass the width of image to `addwatermark` function in helper.php.

```
use Image;

public static function addwatermark ($name, $imageWidth) {
  $watermarkWidth = $imageWidth / 25;
  $watermarkHeight = $watermarkWidth / 8;
  $watermarkSource = 'public/img/watermark/watermark.png';
  $watermark= Image::make($name)->resize($watermarkWidth, $watermarkHeight)->insert($watermarkSource, 'bottom-left', 0, 0);
  $watermark->save($name)->destroy();
}
```

if I get it wrong, please let me know, thank you.